# Unable to hide the horizontal scroll tabs in a long code snipped

Tags: bug, design

I faced the issue on several occasions, so I am reporting it here. Please see the screenshot for a better understanding of my concern.

I use a Mac. Please auto-hide it after, say, 1 second.

The last line always gets clipped when I scroll to the right.

[image]

```
{some long code - hello world - 123 456 sdf adsf adsf adsf adsf as fasf as fas fasd fasd fa sf adsf adsf adsf ads fads fads f dasf}
```